# How to access different URL in AsyncTask in Java/Android

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

Having problems trying to use a different URL from this same class. I will access webpages similar to the below many more times.

I have looked up many different Q/As and tutorials and can't seem find how to pass a URL as a parameter so it is used in the doInBackground method. I call the execute method as such:

```
new RetrieveFeedTask().execute();
```

```
private class RetrieveFeedTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    protected void onPreExecute() {
    }

    protected String doInBackground(Void... urls) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(API_URL_COMPETITIONS); // this is url http://api.football-data.org/v1/competitions
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            try {
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReadelConnection.getInputStream()));
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                String line;
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    stringBuilder.append(line).append("\n");
                }
                bufferedReader.close();
                return stringBuilder.toString();
            } finally {
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("ERROR", e.getMessage(), e);
            return null;
        }
    }

    //entire JSON page is saved in response
    protected void onPostExecute(String response) {
        if(response == null) {
            response = "THERE WAS AN ERROR";
        }
        Log.i("INFO", response);
        try {
            JSONArray comps = new JSONArray(response);
            JSONObject second = comps.getJSONObject(1); //this is array element PremierLeague2016/2017
            compArray.add("Competition");
            compArray.add(second.getString("caption"));
             //i then set this to an ArrayAdapter and show the results in a Spinner.                 adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            competition.setAdapter(adapter);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Appreciate any help!

Comment: I'm confused what the problem is. You need to replace `API_URL_COMPETITIONS` and use any URL you want

Comment: yes but I'll need this URL for only one Spinner, then a different URL for another Spinner and so on. So i need to create instances of this class but it has a different URL each time, if that is possible but not sure how i'll do that.

Comment: It may benefit you to look into using the Volley library and `JsonObjectRequest` or `JsonArrayRequest`

Comment: thanks again, been using Volley there the last while and it's great! much easier.

Comment: Glad to hear. Retrofit is another good one to use, if you feel adventurous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> can't seem find how to pass a URL as a parameter so it is used in the doInBackground method

The AsyncTask class is `AsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result>`. You want a `String` parameter, not a `Void` parameter.

```
private class RetrieveFeedTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
```

Then you can use `protected String doInBackground(String... urls)` (because Void urls don't make sense)

And update your call

```
String url1 = "http://...";
String url2 = "http://...";
new RetrieveFeedTask().execute(url1, url2);
```

And in doInBackground

```
for (String url : urls) {
     try { 
         URL url = new URL(url);
         HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
```

Or, forget the loop... You can simply access `urls[0]` to get the first String value, for example, just be careful of the IndexOutOfBoundsException

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your AsyncTask to receive String (url) as a parameter:

```
//call
String myURL = "http://.....";
new RetrieveFeedTask().execute(myURL);

...

//change parameter type in declaration
private class RetrieveFeedTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        try {
            // get the parameter
            URL url = new URL(urls[0]); 
            ...
```

> https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Answer (score 0):

Your first `Void` in your Async Task class needs to be the argument:

```
private class RetrieveFeedTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Void, String> {
```

Call it by passing the url:

```
new RetrieveFeedTask().execute(url);
```

Get the url inside the Async task:

```
protected String doInBackground(URL... urls) {
     URL url = urls[0];
```

If you want to pass more than one urls, just pass them along:

```
new RetrieveFeedTask().execute(url1, url2);
```

...and retrieve them:

```
    protected String doInBackground(URL... urls) {
     URL url1 = urls[0];
     URL url2 = urls[1];
```

Also, have a look at the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).